# Regex on validates_format_of

Tags: ruby-on-rails, regex

I have a field in a form, and I need it to be registered only if its format equals one of the two regex I am using.

I have tried to use methods, the helper structure validates_format_of with Proc.new, but may not be using the correct syntax or the correct data type

```
private def format_field
  errors.add(
    :field, "The field does not have a valid format."
  )unless[
    /[0-9]{3}\.?[0-9]{3}\.?[0-9]{3}\-?[0-9]{2}/, 
    /[0-9]{2}\.?[0-9]{3}\.?[0-9]{3}\/?[0-9]{4}\-?[0-9]{2}/
  ].include?(field.format)
end
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please [edit] the question and add a tag for the language you are working with.

Answer (score 0):

A simple approach to this is the following:

```
FORMAT_REGEXES = [
  /[0-9]{3}\.?[0-9]{3}\.?[0-9]{3}\-?[0-9]{2}/,
  /[0-9]{2}\.?[0-9]{3}\.?[0-9]{3}\/?[0-9]{4}\-?[0-9]{2}/
].freeze

def validate_format
  return unless FORMAT_REGEXES.find { |regex| field.format =~ regex }
  errors.add(:field, :invalid, message: 'The field does not have a valid format')
end
```

Comment: This code generated an error:
[/[0-9]{2}\.?[0-9]{3}\.?[0-9]{3}\/?[0-9]{4}\-?[0-9]{2}/, /[0-9]{3}\.?[0-9]{3}\.?[0-9]{3}\-?[0-9]{2}/] is not a symbol nor a string.